# What does recursive mean in relation to the git rm -r [filename]

Tags: git, unix

I am working through some tutorials for git and don't understand the difference between running

```
git rm [path/to/file]
```

and

`git rm -r [path/to/file`]

What exactly does the recursive mean?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the git-rm man page:

A leading directory name (e.g. `dir` to remove `dir/file1` and `dir/file2`) can be given to remove all files in the directory, and recursively all sub-directories, but this requires the `-r` option to be explicitly given.

Thus `git rm -r /path/to/file` does the same as `git rm /path/to/file` and stages the file for removal. However `git rm -r /path/to/directory` removes the directory and recursively everything it contains.

Comment: You can also just remove with out git by doing a `rm -rf dir` and then staging with `git add -A`

Answer (score 1):

With `-r` you can remove complete directory trees.